# how to call multiple function on same route method

Tags: node.js

for the post method on "/shareFolder" i want to call two methods at same time,

```
      .post("/shareFolder", FoldersRoutes.notifyUser)
      .post("/shareFolder", FoldersRoutes.shareFolderToUser)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
.post("/shareFolder", function () { 
    FoldersRoutes.notifyUser();
    FoldersRoutes.shareFolderToUser();
});
```